# TclOO: Difference between declaring variable as "class" level or in constructor

Tags: tcl

I'm confused about where to use `variable myVar` and when it's required to use `my variable myVar`

If I define a class like this, there are no errors:

```
oo::class create Foo {
    variable bar

    constructor {input} {
        set bar $input
    }

    method twoBar {} {
        return [expr {2 * $bar}]
    }
}
```

then

```
% set f [Foo new 42]
::oo::Obj12
% $f twoBar
84
```

But if I move `variable bar` into the constructor:

```
oo::class create Foo {
    constructor {input} {
        variable bar
        set bar $input
    }

    method twoBar {} {
        return [expr {2 * $bar}]
    }
}
```

then

```
% set f [Foo new 42]
::oo::Obj12
% $f twoBar
can't read "bar": no such variable
```

This is resolved by adding `my variable bar` into the `twoBar` method.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the method, `variable` is just the regular Tcl command that you know, and the current namespace is the instance namespace (that every object has).

**At the declaration level, `variable` is different.** (It's a different command entirely.) It configures the *variable resolver* for the configured entity (the class `Foo` in the example) to have a variable name that, if it is not found in the local (method) scope, will be looked up in the instance namespace; the resolver actually will do this for a list of variable names. The variable resolver applies to all methods defined by that class — but *not* its subclasses or superclasses (I tried it the other way; it sucked) — or instance if in an instance-defining context.

In your examples, this means that:

1. In the first case, both the constructor and the `twoBar` method have `bar` actually refer to the variable `::oo::Obj12::bar` (under the usual assumptions about namespace names in the TclOO implementation).
2. In the second case, while `bar` refers to `::oo::Obj12::bar` in the constructor (technically, only after the call to `variable`), in the `twoBar` method `bar` only ever refers to a *local* variable that you never set. That means that reading from `bar` fails (because of the standard semantics of variable reading).

---

Calling `my variable bar` has the same effect as `variable bar` inside that method. The difference is that one can be promoted to be callable from outside the object, and the other can bind and set multiple variables at once; both are uncommon uses, but are fundamentally different.

---

At the bytecode level, the only noticeable difference between the two `twoBar` methods is this (in the first version):

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble method Foo twoBar
ByteCode 0x0x7ff5a2845810, refCt 1, epoch 17, interp 0x0x7ff5a2808010 (epoch 17)
  Source "\n        return [expr {2 * $bar}]\n  ..."
  Cmds 2, src 38, inst 6, litObjs 1, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x0x7ff5a2835f10, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 1
      slot 0, scalar, resolved, "bar"
  Commands 2:
      1: pc 0-5, src 9-32        2: pc 0-4, src 17-31
  Command 1: "return [expr {2 * $bar}]..."
  Command 2: "expr {2 * $bar}..."
    (0) push1 0     # "2"
    (2) loadScalar1 %v0     # var "bar"
    (4) mult 
    (5) done
```

The variable `bar` (in slot 0) is marked as “`resolved`” (which does shenanigans under the covers). They are otherwise entirely identical. The constructors have gross differences in the command sequences, so they're tricky to compare, but we can still see what is going on there too.

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble constructor Foo
ByteCode 0x0x7ff5a2845c10, refCt 1, epoch 17, interp 0x0x7ff5a2808010 (epoch 17)
  Source "\n        set bar $input\n  ..."
  Cmds 1, src 28, inst 5, litObjs 0, aux 0, stkDepth 1, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x0x7ff5a2835d90, refCt 1, args 1, compiled locals 2
      slot 0, scalar, arg, "input"
      slot 1, scalar, resolved, "bar"
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-3, src 9-22
  Command 1: "set bar $input..."
    (0) loadScalar1 %v0     # var "input"
    (2) storeScalar1 %v1    # var "bar"
    (4) done
```

Again, `bar` is `resolved`…

Comment: Would you consider the first case as the idiomatic style?